# Does there exist any "quantum Lie algebra" embeded into the quantum enveloping algebra U_q(g)?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

We have known that any finite dim Lie algebra can be embeded into it's enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$, my question is: is there any "quantum Lie algebra" embeded into the quantum enveloping algebra $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$?

The related question is, take $sl(2)$ generated by $\{X,Y,H|[XY]=H, [HX]=2X, [HY]=-2Y\}$ for example, consider the representation on polynomial $K[x,y]$, $K[x,y]$ is in fact a module-algebra over $U(sl(2))$, the  elment of $sl(2)$ can be represented by $X=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, Y=y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, H=x\frac{\partial_q}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial_q}{\partial y}$ (see  Kassel "Quantum groups" (GTM155), pp. 109). In fact, $\{x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, x\frac{\partial_q}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial_q}{\partial y}\}$ generated a three dim Lie subalgbebra (isomorphic to $sl(2)$ under the above correspondence) of derivation algebra of $K[x,y]$.

Similariy, Is there quantum Lie algebra contained in $U_q(sl(2))$? In fact, by Kassel "Quantum groups" (GTM155), pp. 146-149, there is an action of $U_q(sl(2))$ on quantum plane $K_q[x,y],  E=x\frac{\partial_q}{\partial y}, E=y\frac{\partial_q}{\partial x}, K=\sigma_x\sigma_y^{-1}, K^{-1}=\sigma_y\sigma_x^{-1}$ , so is there any finite dim quantum Lie algebra generated by $E,F,K,K^{-1}$, or does the operators  $x\frac{\partial_q}{\partial y}, y\frac{\partial_q}{\partial x}, \sigma_x, \sigma_y^{-1}, \sigma_y, \sigma_x^{-1}$  generate a Lie subalgebra of  of derivation algebra of $K_q[x,y]$?

Comment: Aren't $U(\mathfrak g)$ and $U_q(\mathfrak g)$ isomorphic as algebras, only different as coalgebras?

Comment: @Allen: I'm confused.   How would you construct an algebra isomorphism here?  

@tzhang: What meaning do you attach to the symbol *q* here?   It's used in more than one sense in the literature, sometimes as an indeterminate or arbitrary complex number or root of unity.   Does it matter for your question?

Comment: @Allen, I think the isomorphism occurs when your coefficient ring is a power series ring in the indeterminate $q$. If your coefficient ring is only $\mathbb{C}[q]$, or if $q$ is specialized to a complex value, then there is no reason to expect an algebra isomorphism.

Comment: U(g) and Uq(g) are different as algebras and coalgebras, the relationship between  “different” quantum deformations are given in 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55647/relationship-between-different-quantum-deformations

Comment: I also heard that U_q and U are isomorphic q=e^h and working over C[h], as I  remember it mentioned in the Cartier's Bourbaki talks. As far as I understand reason is simple H^2(g) are trivial - so we cannot deform Lie algebra structure and this also implies we cannot deform U(g) is a reasonably non-trivial way.  Another to look on it - let us look on the category of finite-dim representations of  U(g) - it is semi-simple - so there is no deformation of the category structure, the only thing  we can deform tensor product, this indeed can be done, and tensor category of U_q(g) modules is ...

Comment: equivalent to category of U(g) modules with twisted tensor product, the twisting can be constructed with the Drinfeld's associator.

Answer (score 8):

You might be interested in the notion of a **braided Lie algebra** due to Majid. Roughly speaking this is a coalgebra ${L}$ in a braided category (ie $L$ is an object in a braided category category, with morphisms $\Delta:L \otimes L \to L$, and $\epsilon:L \to C$ satisfying the natural generalization of the axioms of a coalgebra), and in addition a morphism
$$
[ , ]:L \otimes L \to L,
$$
satisfying a "braided version" of the axioms of a Lie algebra.

The notion of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra generalizes to this context, and, quoting from Majid's paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9303148v1.pdf,

> ... the standard quantum deformations $U_q({\frak g})$ are understood
>   as the enveloping algebras of such underlying braided Lie algebras ...

The best place to starting learning about these structures is probably Majid's **Quantum Groups Primer** book.

The paper [arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9510004](http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9510004%20a) mentioned in Jake's answer contains some discussion of these structures.

Comment: So explicitly which subspace $L\subseteq U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ is the braided Lie algebra whose braided enveloping algebra is $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$?

Answer (score 5):

Two seemingly easy to read references are given in the papers 'An introduction to Quantum Lie Algebras' by Delius which is available here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9605026v1.pdf and 'Quantum Lie Algebras associated to $U_q(\mathfrak{gl}_2)$ and $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$' available here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9508013v1.pdf

They explicitly deal with quantized $\mathfrak{sl}_2$; the first link in terms of $U_h(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ and the second in terms of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ which it would appear is the case you are interested in.

These are from the nineties so I am sure more modern references are available.

Comment: Thank you for the references you have given, but it seems that the axioms of "Quantum Lie Algebras" there are not very algebraic explictly. I have found that V. Lyubashenko, A.Sudbery "Quantum Lie algebras of type A_n" http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9510004 and
"Quantum deformations of simple Lie algebras"
http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1997-017-6 more usefull to the problems. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 4):

I hope no one gets offended if I summarize a couple of comments adding few details to it. Truly $U_h(\mathfrak g)$ as an associative algebra is not different from $U(\mathfrak g)[[h]]$ (here $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple, everything is char=0).

This results is just a rigidity result on the associative algebra $U(\mathfrak g)$ (which reflects rigidity of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$). What I wrote inside the bracket seems innocent but it is not: one may say it depends on the fact that the Hochschild cohomology of $U(\mathfrak g)$ is isomorphic to the Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology of $\mathfrak g$. I find this is nicely explained in http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/crossi/LectETHbook.pdf .

When I first saw this result (which is already in the by now classical Chari-Pressley's book) my first impression was "so what's all the fuzz about quantum groups?". The point is that:

1. They are non trivial deformation of the universal enveloping algebra as a **Hopf algebra**.
2. The isomorphism as associative algebras is neither explicit not canonical. We know it exists from purely cohomological arguments...

How does this connect to the embedding $\mathfrak g\hookrightarrow U(\mathfrak g)$? The canonical way to reconstruct $\mathfrak g$ inside $U(\mathfrak g)$ is to identify it with the set of primitive elements (primitive means $\Delta X=X\otimes 1+1\otimes X$). Therefore this embedding depends on the whole Hopf algebra structure (coproduct to determine primitive elements and product to show that they form a Lie algebra and generate a PBW basis).

The set of primitive elements in $U_h(\mathfrak g)$ is trivial and certainly does not allow to reconstruct a PBW basis.

One may look for *twisted* primitive elements with respect to some *group-like* element different from 1. This is an interesting object, it contains the analogue of simple root vectors, but its algebraic properties are rather weak. Still: starting from twisted primtive elements and performing $q$-commutators, in the context of global quantization $U_q(\mathfrak g)$ it is possible to reconstruct all "root vectors" giving a PBW basis. But there is no obvious algebraic structure even on this set of $q$-root vectors.

Of course one may try to understand some kind of embedding $\mathfrak g_h\hookrightarrow U_h(\mathfrak g)$ as a deformation of $\mathfrak g\hookrightarrow U(\mathfrak g)$ as was done in some of the mentioned reference but everything is non canonical and, in my opinion, in the long run it just turns out to be a way of building up an explicit algebra isomorphism; which is known to be technically very complicated.

(this comment does not touch on the "braided" side of the story; that, I do not understand)

Comment: @Nicola Ciccoli nice answer. Concerning the group-like elements let me point the paper "Free-Field Representation of Group Element for Simple Quantum Group" Alexei Morozov, Luc Vinet http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9409093, their claim is that in quantum case group-like elements live in in U_q(g)\otimes Fun_q(G), and the formula exp(g) is substituted by roughly speaking by  exp_q(g*t).  It seems to me that this paper is not so well-known.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks. I am not sure I caught the point of Morozov-Vinet's paper. But let me add here that the sudden switch form $u_h(\mathfrak g)$ to $U_q(\mathfrak g)$ in my answer is due to the fact that group-likes are elements of the form $K=q^H$ where $H$ is in the Cartan of the original Lie algebra, and therefore do require power series in the formal setting but can be considered as generators on the global one. 